# WP Styles/Scripts do not load

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have a plugin called blog-category. In this `blog-category.php` I want to add a style and a script. I tried

```php
function wp_load_assets() {
    $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );

    wp_enqueue_style('tiny-slider-css', plugins_url( 'assets/css/tiny-slider.css', dirname( __FILE__ ) ), array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('tiny-slider-js',  plugins_url( 'assets/js/tiny-slider.js', dirname( __FILE__ ) ), array(), null, true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_load_assets' );
```

But it doesn't load on the page. If I watch the sourcecode I can't find it. The directory should be right. `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` are called in my theme.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Check you console to see what is if the files are called, if you see them there check for the status, if its 404 its most likely because of a wrong path, it will give you an indication on what you need to change to call the file correctly.

Comment: Are you trying to load this in `blog-category.php`? If so, that might be too late for the `wp_enqueue_scripts`. You might want to try to add this to your plugin's main loading php file.

Comment: I copied the code to plugin.php but it didn't change anything. As well nothing appears in the console or in the source code. @disinfor

Comment: @Buttered_Toast

Comment: What is the file structure of your plugin folder?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/1a9b1d9dc4cf459a729e39ebc212f848.png @disinfor
I tried it in plugin.php and blog-category.php

Comment: I could fix it. My plugin used a namespace and that's why I had to call the method with its namespace like:
`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\wp_load_assets' );`